# Android: How to hide other app's launcher

Tags: android

I need to hide OTHER app's luncher. Like this, I user my app `MY` to hide facebook then user can not find it in the phone. Then I show it in `MY`, then the luncher icon show again.

Could it possible?
Just like android 4.0.
[image]
[image]
[image]

————————————————————————————————————

Now I guess it's not google do that things. It should be SamSung. They just hide it in their desktop app. I just realize that the desktop is just a app too. So It can hide/show any apps.

Does anybody have other opinion?

Answer (score 2):

Simply You can't hide the icon of other application. You don' have any permission to do such wrong things with other application.

*Edited*

Note: You have power to hide the System apps and Bloatware on Android from ICS.

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/02/06/how-to-disable-system-apps-in-android-beginners-guide/

Comment: But in android 4.0 I can hide it?

Answer (score 0):

It won't possible to hide other app launcher icon but we can hide our own app

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and for unhiding pass `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`
if you try to hide other app you will experience the **`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`**:`

Comment: I will try it. But I guess it would not work. I guess I have no permission to manage other apps.