# Hide another app launcher icon in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an Android app with a button that when that button pressed I want to hide WhatsApp launcher icon. How can I do that?
I know that I should use `PakageManager` but I have no idea how to use it. I found this code but I have no idea how to use it:

```
ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName("target package name",
                      "target launcher activity");
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                      componentToDisable,
                      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to hide other app's launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813674/android-how-to-hide-other-apps-launcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, outside of some security flaw that I don't know of. Your app can disable your own app's components; your app cannot disable the components of other apps.